# E-mail attachment through intent using `mailto:` scheme

Tags: android, email, gmail

I'm using this code to attach a file:

```
final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
String uriText;
Uri file = Uri.fromFile(new File(path));
uriText = "mailto:" + 
              "?subject=the subject" + 
              "&body=the body of the message"+
              "&attachment="+file;
uriText = uriText.replace(" ", "%20");
Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriText);
emailIntent.setData(uri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
```

(Note that `path` is something like "/sdcard/test.jpg" and that I used `ACTION_SENDTO` because I just want to see e-mail apps in the chooser.)

The intent will provide a list of e-mail applications, but the attachment doesn't appear in Email or Gmail. How can I get the attachment to display?

Comment: Same stuff here. Can't find a way to attach a file to emai lusing ACTION_SENDTO. Using ACTION_SEND works with attachment, but displays loads of crap.

Comment: You should use Uri.Builder() for creating that uriText

Comment: Spent days working on fixing this... Any now updates?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work on my Galaxy Nexus and Nexus 4 (both running stock JellyBean API 17).

Specifically:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts("mailto", "email@me.com", null));
intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(attachmentFile));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send email..."));
```

This does NOT work on my Nexus One (Gingerbread API 10) or older devices. I'm not sure at what point it started working.

Maybe someone else has some more details on this?

When ACTION_SENDTO is not appropriate:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.dir/email");
intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "email@me.com" });
intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(attachmentFile));
```

Comment: I doubt it's fixed in the platform, most likely the Gmail app for that API level does allow this intent. To the platform it's nothing but an intent.

Comment: A good point. Updated my answer. Probably need to query the intent filters to be sure.

Comment: The mime type can't be right either. Your are not actually sending a "vnd.android.cursor.dir/email" as the content. That's why VIEW combined with the appropriate extra's would make sense: "show this url (mailto:) and here's some extra data". But it's up to the apps to support it really.

Comment: I've been using that mime type for years without any problems. I would definitely be interested in hearing of an alternative though. For me, SENDTO is more intuitive than VIEW, but I'm happy to go with whatever works best, of course. Currently, I have no reason to believe VIEW works better than SENDTO.

Answer (score 2):

> The intent will provide a list of e-mail applications, but the
>   attachment doesn't appear in Email or Gmail. How can I get the
>   attachment to display?

I was seeking for years for a solution of this problem why it seems that on some devices or Android versions or mail apps the `Intent.ACTION_SENDTO` is suitable to transfer the attachment informations via `putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.fromFile(...))` while on others it is not.

The answer is quite simple: It depends on the Manifest of the respective mail app. Most mail apps don't have `android:mimeType` in the intent filter of `android.intent.action.SENDTO`.

The only solution to make `Intent.ACTION_SENDTO` generally work with attachments is to tell all makers of mail apps that they should extend their manifest (and the corresponding code) like so:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
    <data android:scheme="mailto" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
    ...
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

This way works for me:

```
public static void sendEmailWithImages(Context context, String emailTo, String emailCC, String subject, String emailText, String type, List<String> filePaths) {
    //need to "send multiple" to get more than one attachment
    final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
    emailIntent.setType(type);
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{emailTo});
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_CC, new String[]{emailCC});
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, emailText);
    //has to be an ArrayList
    ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
    //convert from paths to Android friendly Parcelable Uri's
    if(filePaths != null) {
        for (String file : filePaths) {
            File fileIn = new File(file);
            Uri u = Uri.fromFile(fileIn);
            uris.add(u);
        }
        emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
    }
    try {
        context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, context.getString(R.string.send_email_using_message)));
    }catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        //TODO
    }
}
```

Comment: in list chooser it will just display email , gmail or display all like sms, bluetooth etc...?thx

Comment: Try the method above with android.content.Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, it should work

Comment: about type what should put in? text/plain or message/rfrc822

Comment: The intent isn't specific to *sending an e-mail*. You're basically asking Android to provide a list of applications that support sending a file, which may include anything from Dropbox to Skype. The OP specifically asks how to provide an attachment when specifying the `mailto` scheme for an intent composed from a URI.

Answer (score 0):

This way works for me:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
  Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("mailto:"));
  List<ResolveInfo> pkgAppsList = pm.queryIntentActivities(emailIntent, PackageManager.GET_RESOLVED_FILTER);
  List<LabeledIntent> intentList = new ArrayList<>();
  for(ResolveInfo resolveInfo : pkgAppsList){
    String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setPackage(packageName);
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName, resolveInfo.activityInfo.name));
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("message/rfc822");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{});
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    intentList.add(new LabeledIntent(intent, packageName, resolveInfo.loadLabel(pm), resolveInfo.icon));
  }

  try {
    Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intentList.remove(intentList.size() - 1), "Отправка билета на почту");
    LabeledIntent[] extraIntents = intentList.toArray(new LabeledIntent[intentList.size()]);
    chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, extraIntents);
    startActivity(chooser);
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    Toast.makeText(TicketsActivity.this, "У Вас не установлен почтовый клиент.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
```