# Find Solution to send email

Tags: android, email, android-intent

I am creating utility to send email. In my code i use chooser intent to choose email app to send email. It work perfectly but the problem is that if i use attachment file in this code using Uri then in chooser i choose G-mail, and then G-mail is stopped. If i send email without attachment it work good. Can any one solve my problem. Here is my code.

```
public void SendEmail() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto: "));
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,to);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
//        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Mail..."));
}
```

In this code a line is in comment. if i use this line then G-mail is stopped. I am using this line for file attachment. Help me please.

Comment: check this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/28809905/3983054, it may helps you

Comment: `if i use this line then G-mail is stopped` ... what does this mean?

Comment: check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12741987/1568530 they use a list of extras, maybe that is what gmail expects.

Comment: it means if i use this line in code then gmail app is not working.

Comment: Thanx for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/**Use the below Code Snippet**/

Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.dir/email");
String to[] = {""};
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + "Your URI"));
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."));
```

Comment: Thank you. I solved my problem. Thank you for your support

Comment: @erKaranjeet, how exactly did you solve it? Why don't you share it so other people know the solution?

Comment: On top see second comment on my post @Vlad Matvienko  Give me solution. And that work or me. I use "emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);" for my attachment and it work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code it's works for me correctly:

```
 Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

                String aEmailList[] = {"info@marutinandan.com"};
                //String aEmailCCList[] = { "user3@fakehost.com","user4@fakehost.com"};
                //String aEmailBCCList[] = { "user5@fakehost.com" };

                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, aEmailList);
                // emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_CC, aEmailCCList);
                // emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_BCC, aEmailBCCList);

                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "your subject");

                emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "your message body.");

                startActivity(emailIntent);
```

Comment: Its a normal code for email sending. I want the code for pdf attachment. And thanx for your support. I solved my problem. Thank you.

Comment: where in your code you add attachments? Have you read the question?